# pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [SSL routines::certificate verify failed')

Tags: python, sql-server, ssl, pyodbc

I've created sql server docker container using the below command.

```bash
sudo  docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=Password123#" -p 1433:1433 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
```

The docker container with sql server is running fine.

```bash
~ sudo docker ps  
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                        COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
15ddaf978ba9   mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest   "/opt/mssql/bin/perm…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:1433->1433/tcp, :::1433->1433/tcp        quirky_feistel
```

now I created login and user using below command -

```
~ sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P "Password123#" -C 
1> create database demo;
2> create login demo with password 'Demo123#';
3> alter server role sysadmin add member demo;
4> use demo;
5> create user demo for login demo;
6> alter use demo with default_schema='demo';
7> alter role SA add member demo;
8>
```

now I'm trying to access the database from python using pyodbc using below program.

```py
import pyodbc

SERVER = 'localhost,1433'
DATABASE = 'demo'
USERNAME = 'demo'
PASSWORD = 'Demo123#'
#cnxn_str = f'DRIVER={{ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}};SERVER={SERVER};DATABASE={DATABASE};Integrated_Security=false;Trusted_Connection=yes;UID={USERNAME};PWD={PASSWORD}'
#print(cnxn_str)

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(driver='{ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}',
                      server=SERVER,
                      database=DATABASE,
                      trusted_connection='yes',
                      trust_server_certificate='yes',
                      username=USERNAME,
                      password=PASSWORD)
```

When I run the program I get below error -

```bash
 ./venv/bin/python  pydemo.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/raj/Coding/python/pyodbc-demo/pydemo.py", line 10, in <module>
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect(driver='{ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}',
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:0A000086:SSL routines::certificate verify failed:self-signed certificate] (-1) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Instead of `trust_server_certificate='yes'` have you tried `TrustServerCertificate="yes"`? (i.e.: no underscores.)

Comment: Do SQL server machine and client (python) match ODBC Driver version?
I tried downgrading to ODBC 17 and everything worked out